# Terminal freezes after I close opencv image windows by hitting "x" on GUI

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to run the below program, and I can successfully close the window by pushing any button, but when I close the windows by hitting "x" on windows, my terminal will freeze.

How can I close my window by hitting top-right "x" ?

**OS** : ubuntu-18.04

**python** : 3.6.8

**opencv-contrib-python** : 4.1.1.26

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("images/color.png")
cv2.imshow("dasd", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My terminal 
[image]

Comment: does it work if you remove the `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` line?

Comment: No, it not works for me

Comment: can you try cv2.namedWindow before the imshow?

Comment: I tried it, it also not works for me

Comment: Same here. It shouldn't be like this.